# oracle odm: association rule increasing maximum number of distinct values

Tags: oracle11g, data-mining

I am using the Oracle Data miner
In my workflow I'm joining two tables. A sales table and a product table joined on product key.
Here are the following details in my ar analysis:

Transaction id's - slip number id, location sold id
Item Id - product key
Value - class name

The following works fine except that the class name is still too general a description to get meaningful information about the product.

If I do the following:

Transaction id's - slip number id, location sold id
Item Id - product key
Value - style name (which is part of the product table)

the error message I get is:
Item Value style name has too many distinct values. Maximum number of distinct values allowed is 10

How can I increase the maximum number of distinct values (infinite would be great as some of the tables have 100"s of millions of records).

I don't really understand why there has to be this limitation. Can someone explain it to me?

I am using sql developer 3.2.20.09
And Advanced Analytics version 11.2.0.3.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using too much data.

Do *not* feed numerical data such as item value into association rule mining.

Association rule mining is supposed to find rules such as

```
buys diapers  ->  also buys beer
```

For these algorithm you need records that contain just product categories, nothing else. You usually won't even want to know *which brand* of diapers or beer for this (urban myth) toy example. I.e. you want your input data to be like this:

```
diapers baby-food spaghetti tomatos
diapers beer
diapers baby-food beer
spaghetti tomatos cheese
```

where each line contains the product categories bought together in one transaction.

Then post-process the association rules *afterwards* to e.g. check how much value they contribute, or if there is a particular brand this applies to only (i.e. will they prefer the cheapest or premium beer, when they were sent to the supermarket to buy diapers)

Without the abstraction to product categories, your results will likely not be significant (i.e. you won't find anything).

Comment: Thank you, I am so new to data-mining and BI, presently doing an internship. If you have any useful links it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't do BI or use Oracle. "BI analytics" is usually crappy 30 years old stuff. So I can't give you any links on that.